# Wrongly update all the record after calling a function

Tags: laravel

I am creating an edit function which can edit the posts' caption. Actually, it can successfully update record but it updates all the posts' caption when I just edit one of them. When I submit a edit request, it changed all the post at once.

The project is under Php Laravel and using sqlite for the database management.

PostsController.php

```
public function update(Post $post){
    auth();
    $userid = auth()->user()->id;
    $postuid = $post->user_id;

    if ($postuid == $userid) {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'caption' => 'required',
        ]);

        auth()->user()->posts()->update($data);

        return redirect("/p/{$post->id}");
    }else return abort('403');
}
```

Create_posts_table.php

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->text('caption');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->index('user_id');
});
```

create_user_table.php

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

Expected: it updates each record if I access to its edit page. 
Actual: access one of the edit page and update all the record at once.

Comment: add your route declaration too.

Comment: calling auth()->user()->posts()->update($data) will update all the user posts. you need particular post id to update it.

Comment: update only the `$post` directly: `$post->update($data);`

Comment: Route::patch('p/{post}', 'PostsController@update')->name('post.update');

Comment: @N69S You mean I need to replace posts()->update($data) to $post->update($data)?

Comment: @YukChan exactly

Comment: @ArsiiRasheed it's also my guess of this problem but I am not really know how to edit the code....

Comment: @YukChan your code actually present some vulnerabilities. Tell me if you want some help

Comment: @N69S Sure!!! it's really hard to learn without helps...What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

`auth()->user()->posts()->update($data);` is going to update all `posts()` that are associated with the current `auth()->user()`. If you want to update only the current `Post`, simply do

```
$post->update($data);
```

Route Model binding, via `Post $post` in your function will find a `Post` instance related to the ID in the URL, so you can simply update that.

Comment: Thank you so much!! the explanation really helps!

Answer (score 2):

Do it this way:

```
public function update(Post $post){
    auth();
    $userid = auth()->user()->id;
    $postuid = $post->user_id;

    if ($postuid == $userid) {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'caption' => 'required',
        ]);

        // update only the specific post, not all posts belonging to user
        $post->update($data);

        return redirect("/p/{$post->id}");
    }else return abort('403');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not use the method `update` without some security.

First rule in dev is to never trust client input. For example, if the request contain the input `user_id` having a value other than the id of the current user, your code will change the owner of the post.

In this case there is no sensitive fields but...

Here is a good example (will explain it in the code):

```php
public function update($postId){ //remove model injection and use the post ID.

    //validate data you can use FormRequest class extention in the method parameters instead
    $data = request()->validate([
        'caption' => 'required',
        'not_required_field' => 'string',
    ]);

    //get the post from the relation of the user, if the post doesnt exist or is not the user's post, it will return a 404 response.
    $user = auth()->user();
    $post = $user->posts()->findOrFail($postId);

    //get the data one variable at a time it's more safe. The input method second parameter is the default to set
    $caption = request()->input('caption');
    $notRequiredField = request()->input('not_required_field', '');

    //now you can update
    $post->caption = $caption;
    $post->not_required_field = $notRequiredField;
    $post->save();

    //result of success
    return redirect("/p/{$post->id}");
}
```

Dont forget to change `{$post}` to `{$postId}` in the route.

Comment: ohhhh, i am always thinking about the security problem of the if-else function. Thanks!!! May I ask you questions by email you?

Comment: @YukChan we can chat here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201895/laravel-help

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow...I cannot use the chatroom function

Comment: @YukChan hope you got my message